# If an A mathematical Arrangement equal Zero Add One

Tags: r

I have this mathematical arrangement that is true for all integers except `2`. I want to sutract 2 from any positive integer(let me stop at 10 for minimum working example's sake). I want `ov` to be `l-2` if `l = seq(n - 2) + 1`

```
n <- length(1:10) 
l <- seq(n - 2) + 1
ov <- l-2
```

> l = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

`ov` is true for all my positive integers except `2` that is `0`. I want to give a condition that whenever it encounters a ``FALSE`situation it should add`1`to the equation of`ov` as:

```
ov <- l-2; ov + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `pmax`.

```
pmax(ov, 1)
#[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Or an `ifelse`.

```
ifelse(ov == 0, ov + 1, ov)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand but you can try:

```
ov[(l - 2) == 0] = ov[(l - 2) == 0] + 1
ov
```

Output:

```
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: I can not get your output here, I got `5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DanielJames Are you running the same code you're running in your question?

Comment: @DanielJames If not please show the actual code you're running with in the question...

Comment: I got your output right now.

Comment: @DanielJames Does it work?